# How to set content type as plain/text in padrino?

Tags: content-type, runtime-error, plaintext, padrino, media-type

I want to return a string in response with content type as plain/text. This is what I am doing currently.

```
 get :index, :map => "/ivr", :provides => [:plain]  do
   "Hello World!"
 end
```

It says ;

```
RuntimeError - Unknown media type: :plain:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provides take content_type from here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/mime.rb#L546

So the correct match is:

```
:provides => :text
```

Then you are also be able to set custom mime_types like:

```
get :index do
  content_type 'text/plain;charset=utf8'
  "Im plain"
end
```

Comment: Note that if you're doing a Rack test, you may have to do `get '/foo.text'` (awkward).  However, `:provides => :txt` is equivalent and allows `'/foo.txt'` instead.